# System of recurrences

Tags: recurrence-relations

I want to solve the following recurrences system:

$$p_t=\frac{n-2}{2(n-1)}p_{t-1}+\frac{1}{2(n-1)}q_{t-1}+\frac{1}{2}r_{t-1}$$
$$q_t=\frac{1}{2}p_{t-1}+\frac{1}{2}s_{t-1}$$
$$r_t=\frac{n-2}{2(n-1)}r_{t-1}+\frac{1}{2(n-1)}s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}p_{t-1}$$
$$s_t=\frac{1}{2}r_{t-1}+\frac{1}{2}q_{t-1}$$

with the following initial conditions:

$p_0=0, p_1=\frac{1}{2(n-1)}$

$q_0=1, q_1=0$

$r_0=0, r_1=0$

$s_0=0,s_1=\frac{1}{2}$

Is there any intelligent way to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recursion can be solved in closed form by the following technique:

Start from the defining equations for $\{p_k,q_k,r_k,s_k\}$.  Work instead (trick 1) with variables
$$
m_k = p_k +r_k \\n_k =p_k -r_k \\ f_k = q_k+s_k \\ g_k = q_k-s_k
$$
so that if we obtain closed forms for the new variables, $p_k = \frac12(m_k+n_k)$ and so forth. Call these four new recursions the $mnfg$ recursions.

Simultaneously solve (trick 2) the second and fourth equations (that came from the $q_k$ and $s_k$ recursions) for $f_{k-1}$ and $g_{k-1}$.   Use those values of  $f_{k-1}$ and $g_{k-1}$ to eliminate those variables in the first and third equations, which now involve various indices of $m_{k-i}$ and $m_{k-i}$ but no longer have any $f$ and $g$ variables except $f_k$ and $g_k$.

Simultaneously solve those new first and third equations for $f_k$ and $g_k$, which gives
$$
f_k = (2-n)m_{k-1} + (n-1) m_k\\
g_k = (1-n)n_k
$$
Now comes trick 3: replace $k$ with $k-1$ in those $f_k,g_k$ relations to acquire the relations 
$$
f_{k-1} = (2-n)m_{k-2} + (n-1) m_{k-1}\\
g_{k-1} = (1-n)n_{k-1}
$$
Now you can use those $f$ and $g$ expressions to eliminate all the $f$ and $g$ variables from the $mnfg$ recursions.  The fourth of those new recursions (which we will cal the $mn$ recursions) reads
$$
(3n-4)m_{k-1} = (n-2) m_{k-2}+(2n-2)m_k +n\,n_{k-1} + (2n-2)n_k
$$
Solve this for $n_{k-1}$ and substitute that into all of the $mn$ recursions; of course the fourth one becomes an identity, but actually, the first one also is identically satisfied with this expression for $n_{k-1}$, and the second and third recursions are just multiples of each other. That tells us we have made a wise choice for the new variables.

We are left with one second order recursion in $m_k$:
$$
m_k = \frac{3n-4}{2n-2} m_{k-1} - \frac{n-2}{2n-2} m_{k-2}
$$

This is solved by the usual technique (trick 4) of assuming a solution in the form $m_k= C\alpha^K$; the recursion then gives
$$
\alpha^2 - \frac{3n-4}{2n-2}\alpha + \frac{n-2}{2n-2} = 0
$$
which has two solutions, $\alpha = 1$, $\alpha = \frac{n-2}{2n-2}$. So 
$$
m_k = C + D  \left(\frac{n-2}{2n-2}\right)^k
$$

Applying the initial conditions we fix $C$ and $D$:
$$
m_k = \frac1n \left[ 1 - \left(\frac{n-2}{2n-2}\right)^k \right]
$$

Next, we have $f_k$ in terms of $m_k$, and this becomes
$$
f_k= \frac1n\left[ 1+(n-1)\left(\frac{n-2}{2n-2}\right)^k\right]
$$
To find $n_k$ it is best to go back to the $mnfg$ recursions, applying the close forms we now have for $m_k$ and $f_k$. We get four identical equations, which boil down to 
$$
n_k = -\frac{n}{2n-2}n_{k-1}
$$
The solution, respecting the initial value for $n_1$ is
$$
n_k = -\frac1n\left(\frac{n}{2-2n}\right)^k
$$
(This form is is not valid for $k=0$ but it is for all $k>0$.)

$g_k$ is easy once we have $n_k$; a bit of simplification gives:

$$
g_k = -2^{-k}\left(\frac{n}{1-n}\right)^{k-1}
$$

So the final answer for $\{p_k,q_k,r_k,s_k\}$, valid for all $k>0$, is:
$$
p_k = \frac12\left( \frac1n \left[ 1 - \left(\frac{n-2}{2n-2}\right)^k \right] 
- \frac1n\left(\frac{n}{2-2n}\right)^k \right) \\
q_k = \frac12\left(  \frac1n\left[ 1+(n-1)\left(\frac{n-2}{2n-2}\right)^k\right] 
 -2^{-k}\left(\frac{n}{1-n}\right)^{k-1}\right)\\
r_k = \frac12\left( \frac1n \left[ 1 - \left(\frac{n-2}{2n-2}\right)^k \right] 
+ \frac1n\left(\frac{n}{2-2n}\right)^k \right) \\
s_k = \frac12\left(  \frac1n\left[ 1+(n-1)\left(\frac{n-2}{2n-2}\right)^k\right] 
+2^{-k}\left(\frac{n}{1-n}\right)^{k-1}\right)
$$

Comment: How could you know that the change of variables you used works?

Comment: The recursions treat $p$ and $r$ in a very symmetric way; similarly for $q$ and $s$. So if we extract the "gross" behaviors of the average of $p$ and $r$ (similarly for $q$ and $s$ we can be sure to reduce this to a system of two recursions, and those are often easy to solve by turning them into a single second-order recursion..  Then the rest of the behavior is encapsulated in the difference between $p$ and $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Failing any easier solution, you can follow the method I outlined in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2014409/131456). It will be a little cumbersome doing the calculations but Mathematica can find the diagonalization for the transition matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b & 0.5 & 0.5\\0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.5\\0.5 &0 & a & b\\0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0\end{pmatrix}  $$

where $a = \frac{n-2}{2(n-1)}$ and $b= \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$.

Comment: That method is not so good; the $p,q,r,s$ quantities have simple rational values and at least for small integer $n$ fal into an easily observed pattern, while the eigenvalue method either needs to solve a hairy cubic or get numerical results which don't give a clue to the pattern.